# clustering for users with multiple features, each feature has different shape

Tags: cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to do clustering for users.I have multiple users, each with five features. The first feature is a time series sequence with a shape of [20, 5]. The second feature is a regular feature with a shape of [1, 16]. The third feature is a time series sequence with a shape of [3, 1]. The fourth feature is a time series feature with a shape of [5, 1]. The fifth feature is a time series sequence with a shape of [6, 1]. I want to perform clustering based on these features.

How can I do clustering for this case? Can anyone give a hint?

I tried to do dimension reduction for the time series sequences and concat the features all together.But I am not sure if it is a good idea.Dimension reduction may cause information loss for time series sequence?